# Copy table rows between SQL Server CE databases

Tags: visual-studio-2005, sql-server-ce

I have 2 SQL Server CE databases, during development I want to copy the changes made to the database (added rows) on the mobile device to my local "source" database.

I can open both databases in VS2005 and see the changes that have been made. But how can I get the data from the mobile to the local.

Simply replacing the local DB with the one from the device, causes the app to crash during the following build.

Thanks

Comment: Copying from device to desktop should work, what errors are you getting?

Comment: So I restarted my PC (well it crashed) and since then the swapping of files is fine.
Would still like to know if it's possible to copy rows between DBs, or if that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems copying SQL CE databases to flash drives only to find that the copy is corrupted.  The corrupted database works fine after recovering in Visual Studio, but until then it won't load in my application.  Not sure if this is the same problem you are facing.

Depending on how your application retrieves data from the database, copying rows from one SQL CE database to another should work fine.